# Issues running multiple Shells on Tasker for Android

Tags: android, tasker

I'm currently using Tasker on Android and I want to create a task using 2 Run Shell's. The setup I have is...

1.Wait
*MS* 0 *Seconds* 10 *Minutes* 0 *Hours* 0

2.Run Shell
*Command* input tap 550 580

3.Wait
*MS* 0 *Seconds* 10 *Minutes* 0 *Hours* 0

4.Run Shell
*Command* input tap 550 1800

Currently the first Run Shell works fine but the second Run Shell never executes. Don't understand why it's not running the second Run Shell.

Answer (score 0):

there might be few reasons for that:

1. you are pointing wrong coordinates
2. app, you're trying to interact with, does not support accessibility features
3. you do not have accessibility features enabled
4. other

to achieve your goal, I'd recommend using Tasker's plugin called [AutoInput](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoinput)
as it gives you way more control over what you click, focus, type etc

Answer (score 0):

One action need. Run Shell Command:

```
sleep 10m
input tap...
sleep 10m
input tap...
```